# how to align image in the box to the right without using float

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to align images in my code to the right, so that I have to boxes, in two rows both aligned to their sides, left and right With text and links under them, I tried alot of Things amongs others, float, but it never worked without some problem
this is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,intial-scale=1">
        <title>Marko's portfolio</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="img-responsive logo" alt="Responsive image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
                    <h1>Name</h1>
                    <h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <hr class="line">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <img class="img-responsive picture" alt="Responsive image" src="images/ideja.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Featured Work</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-thin text-center">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project1">
                        <h3>Appify</h3>
                    <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
                    <h3>Appify</h3>
                    <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-thin text-center">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Responsive image">
                    <h3>Appify</h3>
                    <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Responsive image">
                    <h3>Appify</h3>
                    <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is css

```css
body { font-family: 'Fredericka the Great', cursive;
}

.display {}

.text-thin{font-size: 14px;
}

.line {border-top-width:0px;height:2px;background-color:rgb(42,35,35);
}

.logo { margin-top:20px;
}

.picture { width:1440px; height:500px;}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `margin-left` with % like so :

```
.logo { 
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left: 40%;
}
```

for the other images :

```
.col-md-6 img {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

edit regard to your comment you want the image to fit the hole size of the container , so you do like follow :

```
.col-md-6 img {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epguw3z3/3/)**

Comment: I tried to play with the margins, but than I have problems with responsivnes, and the images that I have problem with are http://placehold.it/555x300

Comment: the respensive issue is because of this .picture { width:1440px; height:500px;}

Comment: this is not working for me since I want to align my images on the right side, all the way to the right, and the images on the left side all the way to the left side

Comment: put a fluid width instead of "px" one , and i don't understand why the width is this larger !!

Comment: well, I wanted the image to be wide as a whole container

Comment: thank you very much for Your effort, but I wasn't Clear maybe, I am not having a problem with logo image, but with the 4 images that are in 2 rows, under the biggest image on the site.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, now I see that it works for those images too, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should apply a clearfix or just precise overflow of box and set img float right and text in an container float left like:

```
<div class="col-md-6 clearfix project">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300" alt="Responsive image">
    <div class="description">
        <h3>Appify</h3>
        <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.project {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.project .description {
    float: left;
}
.description {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: he said without using float !!

Comment: "float, but it never worked without some problem" just purpose a fine solution with and show why it doesn't work.

Comment: I can align them, but when I use float or play with margins when I have center-block and start minimizing browser the images don't stack under each other like they do when I leave the images at the center of the columns.  Would like to post an image but I don't have the rights yet